# Update cell values based on dependent drop down lists/multiple criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I've created a google sheet with dependent drop down lists based on this [script](http://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com/google-sheets-apps-script-dynamic-dependent-dropdown-data-validation-lists/)/[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-I8Z4nTDak). [Here's a copy of the sheet I've created.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qZEONCsIyFWT9J9f9Fp6NPco5Ro3NFmlpgUqcUkfgm0/edit?usp=sharing) Instead of creating a drop down list like the one currently present in column C of the master sheet, my goal is to auto populate cells in column C with each unique value available in the drop down list. I've attempted this via [VLOOKUP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718752/updating-cell-values-based-on-selection-in-drop-down-list-in-google-spreadsheet) but only got errors in response, likely due to a lack of validation or some other form of logic I'm not familiar with. I'm also interested in having the populated options in column C clear (clearContent) if either column A or column B options are modified, similar to how the current script works. Any help in figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sorry about that, should be fixed/public now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When the drop down lists of the column "A" and column "B" are changed, you want to put the related values of the column "C" in the sheet of "options" to the cells of column "C".

  - For example, when the drop down lists of the column "A" and column "B" are `apple` and `1_dormant`, you want to put the values of `Phytophthora collar rot, European red mite, Scale` to the cells of column "C".
- When the drop down lists of the column "A" and column "B" are changed, you want to clear the column "C" of the sheet of `master`.
- You want to achieve this using the OnEdit event trigger with Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I think that `listToApply` of the function of `applySecondLevelValidation` can be used. Using this, the values can be put to the column "C".
- About the script for clearing the column "C", I think that `ws.getRange(2, 3, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 1).clearContent();` can be used.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify the functions of `applyFirstLevelValidation` and `applySecondLevelValidation` as follows.

```
function applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r){
    ws.getRange(2, 3, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 1).clearContent(); // Added

    if(val===""){
      ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){return o[0] == val });
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return o[1]})
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    }
}

function applySecondLevelValidation(val,r){
    ws.getRange(2, 3, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 1).clearContent(); // Added

    if(val===""){
      ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r,firstLevelColumn).getValue();
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){return o[0] == firstLevelColValue && o[1] === val});
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return [o[2]]}); // Modified
      ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn,listToApply.length, 1).setValues(listToApply); // Modified
    }
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to put the values to only the cell "C2", please modify above script as follows.

  - From

    ```
    var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return [o[2]]});
    ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn,listToApply.length, 1).setValues(listToApply);
    ```
  - To

    ```
    var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return o[2]});
    ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).setValue(listToApply.join(","));
    ```

#### References:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @hortsystems Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.