# Update google script to clear a specific range of cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I'm updating a google sheet [(here's a copy)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13KDUubzw_-Rv_FoitlcpOl_T1X4uxmKFTu5IOTcI4m8/edit?usp=sharing) based on some help I received on stackexchange [last year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59382567/update-cell-values-based-on-dependent-drop-down-lists-multiple-criteria). 
The script works fine in that the populations in column D clear if either option in columns B or C are modified, but instead of clearing the entire column, I'm wondering if it is possible to clear a specific range of cells within a column, for example cells D6:D11, D13:D18, D20:D25, etc., so that I can have a heading that isn't cleared in the cell directly above those ranges (D5,D12,D19). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: the script is below

```
var mainWsName = "master";
var optionsWsName = "e154simple";
var firstLevelColumn = 2; 
var secondLevelColumn = 3; 
var thirdLevelColumn = 4; 
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(mainWsName);
var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(optionsWsName);
var options = wsOptions.getRange(2,1,wsOptions.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();


function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName === mainWsName && c=== firstLevelColumn && r>1){
    applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r);
  } else if(wsName === mainWsName && c=== secondLevelColumn && r>1) {
    applySecondLevelValidation(val,r)
  }
} //end onEdit

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r){
    ws.getRange(3, 4, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 1).clearContent(); // Added

    if(val===""){
      ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){return o[0] == val });
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return o[1]})
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    }
}

function applySecondLevelValidation(val,r){
    ws.getRange(3, 4, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 1).clearContent(); // Added

    if(val===""){
      ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r,firstLevelColumn).getValue();
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){return o[0] == firstLevelColValue && o[1] === val});
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return [o[2]]}); // Modified
      ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn,listToApply.length, 1).setValues(listToApply); // Modified
    }
}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();

  cell.setDataValidation(rule)
}
```

Comment: Please share a copy of your current script

Comment: I've edited my post, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will be what you are looking for.

```
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A2:A3').clearContent()
```

This will leave A1 alone(your header, like D5 in your example) and clear out A2 and A3(like D6:D11 in your example).

The key will be to create a string with the cell names like getRange('A2' + : + 'A3')
so that you will be able to specify the range to clear in your column.

I found this in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent).